# Dynamic Diamond Operator Parameters

Tags: java, javafx

I have the following code:

```
@FXML
TableView dataTable;

for(HashMap column : columns){

    String dataType = (String)column.get("DATA_TYPE");

    if(dataType.matches("char|date")){
        TableColumn<String, String> tableColumn;
    }else if(dataType.matches("int")){
        TableColumn<String, Integer> tableColumn;
    }else{
        TableColumn<String, String> tableColumn;
    }

    tableColumn = new TableColumn<>((String)column.get("COLUMN_NAME"));
    dataTable.getColumns().add(tableColumn);
}
```

What I am not sure about, is the Diamond Operators. The second value of that operator will change depending on what is in the database. The issue I am having, is that it says that it can't find `tableColumn` on this line:

```
tableColumn = new TableColumn<>((String)column.get("COLUMN_NAME"));
```

Is there a solution that will allow me to have dynamically changing Diamond Operator parameters?

Comment: You have a problem with variable scope. You have a larger problem though. Generics are a compile time concept. You want runtime behavior.

Comment: Related (and informative): [Variable Scope Tutorial](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html) and [Official Generics Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/). These are required reading before you proceed, otherwise you will not have the basics necessary to understand how these things are used (and what their limitations are) or to start to solve your stated problem (or to fully understand any correct answers to your question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare one

```
 TableColumn<String, Object> tableColumn
```

and use this, but keep track of the class of values (according to column.get("DATA_TYPE"). You may use this to branch processing when you extract values, cast to the approproate data type.

Not very elegant, but since the data is any of three types...